# Formatting twoway graph

Tags: stata

I am struggling to make two changes to a `twoway connected` graph in Stata.

I cannot manage to make the background white instead of the standard light blue even if I include `graphregion(color(white))`.

I want the notes to be at the bottom of the figure where it currently says "Graphs by car type" instead of below each country's graph.

My code is as follows:

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway (connected price mpg) (connected headroom mpg), by(foreign) ///
       legend(order(1 "AAA" 2 "BBB")) ///
       graphregion(color(white)) ///
       xtitle(Date) ytitle("Dummy Chart") ///
       note("Footnote 1" "Footnote 2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using an out-of-date version of Stata (i.e. a version < 18) if you are getting a "standard light blue", but you can fix that by using almost any scheme other than `s2color`.

Try

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway (connected price mpg) (connected headroom mpg), by(foreign, note("Footnote 1" "Footnote 2")) ///
       legend(order(1 "AAA" 2 "BBB")) ///
       scheme(s1color) ///
       xtitle(Date) ytitle("Dummy Chart")
```